# How to add directory containing libraries to ghc and ghci's paths by default

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci

I am learning Haskell. I want to use the `System.Random` library. However, Ghci cannot seem to find it. Here is the error reported

```
Prelude> import System.Random 

<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude>
```

So I installed the library using `cabal install random`. The same problem persisted. After a bit of poking around in my directories I found that the package *is* present after all. Here are the contents of my `~/.cabal/lib` 
directory

```
smbud@gedanken:~/.cabal/lib$ ls
bifunctors-4.1.1.1                  distributive-0.4.4  lens-family-core-1.0.1  StateVar-1.1.0.3             unix-2.7.1.0
comonad-4.2.7.2                     exceptions-0.8.2.1  nats-1.1                tagged-0.8.3                 unordered-containers-0.2.7.0
contravariant-1.4                   gnuplot-0.5.4.1     process-1.4.2.0         temporary-1.2.0.4            utility-ht-0.0.11
data-accessor-0.2.2.7               graphene-0.1.0.4    random-1.1              time-1.5.0.1                 void-0.7.1
data-accessor-transformers-0.2.1.7  hashable-1.1.2.5    semigroupoids-4.3       transformers-compat-0.4.0.3
directory-1.2.5.1                   lens-family-1.0.0   semigroups-0.18.1       transformers-compat-0.5.1.4
```

So I think ghci probably does not search in this directory for libraries? 
What must I do so that ghci can know the loction of `random` and the other 
useful software packages within.

Comment: All of my problems with imports went away when I started using stack....

Comment: Did you, by any chance, use `cabal repl` in a project, where `random` isn't listed as a dependency? That being said, what is your path, what is the result of `cabal list --installed --simple-output`, `ghc-pkg list` and `ghc-pkg list --user`? I couldn't reproduce this with a fresh install of GHC 7.10.3 and cabal-install-1.24.

Comment: and using  -i option of ghci (ghci -i dir)?

Comment: First order of business is checking that libraries are sane. Run `ghc-pkg check` (you can safely ignore any haddock warnings). Also, ghci doesn't know anything about cabal, and looks for (user-installed) packages in `~/.ghc/<platform>/package.conf.d/`

Comment: I followed the same procedure as you with ghc-8.0.1. I didn't have any trouble loading `System.Random` after installing `random` with cabal. Did you end up solving your issue?